# Error with ios application if there is no internet connection on the devices

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application on the apple store, if the device is connected to the internet, the application works well, otherwise, if the device is not connected the application doesn't open, what I want is to popup a message to tell the user there is no connection, or if there is a method to launch the application with the last page opened on this device (offline browser).
Thank you per advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) library for your purpose. This library handles the Internet connection states.

To load from the last saved data, you can use [Property Lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Comment: I download the library, but I have errors with implementing it in my code, for the second issue I am reading my data from json file, I want something like offline browser

Comment: If you are using ARC you should disable it or under build phases > compile sources add -fno-objc-arc to your .m file to make it run with ARC enabled

Comment: ok thank you, it solves the problem with errors, but if I disconnect from the internet, the application gives me an error which is :"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'" what means no data because no internet connection

Comment: You should also handle the situation of first load while offline, this could be considered as special case. In this case, you can give an alert such as "Please connect to the internet for the first load", then you can always use your filled json for offline loading.

Comment: that is what i did, if there is no connection, an alert should appears, but before it appears the error of parameter nil displays, I want when I check the connection, stop execution the rest of code, but i don't want how

Comment: I put this in my code: `Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
    if(![reach isReachable])
    {
        connection = @"no connection";
        NSLog(@"%@", connection);
        SIGSTOP;
          }
    else{
         connection = @"good connection";
    }
    [self showAlarm:connection];  
    [reach startNotifier];` the alert "good connection" displays well if it is connected to the internet, otherwise the above error (parameter is nil) displays when no connection and no alert has displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apple's Reachability class to receive notifications about your network status.

```
#define kReachabilityChangedNotification @"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification"
```

set up a observer for the above notification and when you receive it act accordingly.